# Implementing a stack using nodes, the top node pointer is not known outside the function, top pointer is always NULL

Tags: c, stack

Here is my C program to implement a stack (with nodes as linked list). I am creating a new stack, return the pointer, and then calling the rpn_stack_push() function with the pointer and the data I want to assign to.

But apparently the top node of the stack is always NULL even though I am updating it at the rpn_stack_push() function.

Why is this happening and is there a way to fix it without changing my function definitions?

```
struct _rpn_stack{
        int data;
        struct _rpn_stack *link;
};

typedef struct _rpn_stack rpn_stack_t;

rpn_stack_t* rpn_stack_new() {
    rpn_stack_t *top;
    top = NULL;
    return top;
}

void rpn_stack_push(rpn_stack_t *s, void *data) {
    rpn_stack_t* temp = malloc(sizeof(rpn_stack_t));

    temp->data = (int) *((int*) data);
    temp->link = s;
    s = temp;
}

int main()
{
    rpn_stack_t* n;
    n  =  rpn_stack_new();

    int a =  12;
    int c = 13;
    int* d =  &c;
    int* b =  &a;

    rpn_stack_push(n,  d);
    rpn_stack_push(n,  b);


    while (n != NULL)
    {
      printf("%d -> ", n->data);
      n = n->link;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Normally it should print 13->12->, but it is not going to the loop at all because the top node of the stack (n) is NULL!

Comment: Even after fixing your allocation scheme, I hope it is clear that your "print" loop will leak every node in the stack to the ether, as each node pointer is abandon without being freed. Just saying.. Regarding your allocation scheme, you're passing-by address the wrong thing to your push. The stack head should be passed by address (pointer to pointer to allow dereferenced modification); the `int` values should be passed by value. Obviously the function, including decl, has to change for that reality.

Answer (score 0):

`void rpn_stack_push(rpn_stack_t *s, void *data)` is used with rpn_stack_t *s mean you used call by value parameter, after calling this function, the s pointer don't change its value.
So, please change protype of function `rpn_stack_push` from `void rpn_stack_push(rpn_stack_t *s, void *data)` to `void rpn_stack_push(rpn_stack_t **s, void *data)` as folowing:

```
void rpn_stack_push(rpn_stack_t **s, void *data) {
      rpn_stack_t* temp = (rpn_stack_t*)malloc(sizeof(rpn_stack_t));

      temp->data = (int) *((int*)data);
      temp->link = *s;
      *s = temp;
}
```

And when call it please replace the lines:

```
rpn_stack_push(n,  d);
rpn_stack_push(n,  b);
```

by

```
rpn_stack_push(&n,  d);
rpn_stack_push(&n,  b);
```

It should work then.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried it, it works like this, but my question is, is it possible to keep my function definition and to just change the struct if that is needed to make it work, without changing the function definition of the push(), do you suggest any way how can I achieve this?

Comment: how about this? is that your idea? `rpn_stack_t* rpn_stack_push(rpn_stack_t *s, void *data) { rpn_stack_t* temp = malloc(sizeof(rpn_stack_t));

    temp->data = (int) *((int*) data);
    temp->link = s;
    s = temp; return s; }`

Comment: No  I want to only change the struct or to add any global variable but not the function definitions, is that possible?